# Syntax highlighting with Prettify and Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, syntax-highlighting, google-code-prettify

Im trying to get syntax highlight in my `<pre></pre>` tags, but im using Bootstrap.. Im using Prettify right now, but it dosent work.. If you have a fix please share!
*Basic the code i have right now, just cleaned up.*

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="prettify.js"></script>

<pre>
    <?php
        function hw(){
            echo "Hallo World";
        }
    ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: you have rewrite the CSS structure, the prettify css and your existing css are having some common classes, try to identify them and separate them.

Comment: Prettify dont have a CSS file..

Comment: there was no css doc with Prettify.

Comment: @AndreasMyrupLarsen, http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/prettify.css is the CSS file.  It should be part of all packaged releases.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a class to tell prettify that the content is code, and you probably need to escape your PHP tags:

```
    <pre class="prettyprint">
        &lt;?php
            function hw(){
                echo "Hallo World";
            }
        ?&gt;
    </pre>
```

Also, make sure you're calling `prettyPrint()` somewhere.

The [README](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) file suggests

```
<body onload="prettyPrint()">
```